# Implement template function for generic parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose I have a template function, and I wish to implement it for a specific parameter. This is simple:

```
template<typename T>
T foo();

// specific implementation for int
template<>
int foo() { /*...*/ }

// generic implementation
template<typename T>
T foo() { /*...*/ }
```

What if I need to have a specific implementation for a *family* of types? By *family* I mean a type with template parameter(s) of its own, e.g. `std::vector`. Let's say I happen to know which vector types I will need. Then I can do this:

```
template<typename T>
T foo();

// specific implementation for std::vector<int>
template<>
std::vector<int> foo() { /*...*/ }

// specific implementation for std::vector<long>
template<>
std::vector<long> foo() { /*...*/ }

struct SomeOtherType { /*...*/ };
// specific implementation for std::vector<SomeOtherType>
template<>
std::vector<SomeOtherType> foo() { /*...*/ }

// generic implementation
template<typename T>
T foo() { /*...*/ }
```

If the implementations of `foo()` for those vector types are the same, this is a little bit redundant. What if I don't know all the vector types beforehand, but need the implementation for any `std::vector<V>` to be different than the generic implementation? Either way, it would be nice to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T foo();

// specific implementation for any kind of std::vector
template<???>
std::vector<V> foo() { /*...*/ }

// generic implementation
template<typename T>
T foo() { /*...*/ }
```

Is there a way to do something like this? Can the design be re-worked to make this possible/easier?

Comment: is it only `std::vector<some_type>` or do you want to include more in the "family" ?

Comment: I want to include more in the "family". I happen to know all of the types in the "family" in my use case, but I'm interested in being concise, and also interested to know how to approach this if I didn't know them all.

Comment: you could use a typetrait `belongs_to` that has a tag as member alias such that you can specialize for `belongs_to<T>::family`. Its just a tiny bit more involved than what you find in the duplicate. If you clarify the question (currently it looks like only `std::vector<T>` would be fine) and the duplicate does not answer your question I'd vote to reopen

Comment: The duplicate marking might be correct; I'm still looking at that. Perhaps I misunderstood when you asked about the "family". I need several types, but they all are specializations of `std::vector`.

Comment: ok, no then stay with the duplicate.